# Find out the calling command from Python

Tags: python, command

I have a Python script that can be executed from the shell either as:

```
mpirun run.py
```

or as:

```
python run.py
```

Is it possible, in `run.py`, to find out if the code was called with the `mpirun` or `python` command?

Comment: The script always ends up executed by `python` no matter how it's invoked from the command line. You could make `mpirun` an alias that adds an extra command line or sets an environment variable or something of the sort, however, specifically for this detection.

Comment: Thanks kindall for pointing me to that answer and for the explanation. Yes, looking at an evironmental variable, e.g., `os.environ.has_key("OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE")` solves my problem.